# Excel VBA - trying to find a date in a row of dates, get "object variable or with block variable not set" error

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the summary of what I'm trying to do: 
I have two files, "yyy" is an extract from a system keeping track of sicknesses and holidays, "xxx" file is where we manually note down those things, so I'm trying to make a macro that would cross check the two and highlight consistency/inconsistency in the extract.

Problem: 
When I run the macro, I get an error "object variable or with block variable not set" when it gets to the following

Set y = Range(Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("J2:NZ2").Find(dates.Value).Address)
I tried to swap between the dates.value and dateStr as reference for what to find, but get the same error.

PS. I checked all the ranges over and over and over, everything seem to be correct.
PPS. I probably have some extra defined bits, which aren't present in the code otherwise, apologies for the untidy code. I'm trying to mover past this error to finish the rest of it...

Many thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Sub sickhol_check()

Dim names, dates, schedDates, n, schedName, x, y As Range

Dim wb, WBschedule As Workbook
Dim ws, WSschedule As Worksheet
Dim nameStr As String
Dim dateStr As Long

Set wb = Workbooks("yyy.xlsm")
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WBschedule = Workbooks("xxx.xlsm")
Set WSschedule = WBschedule.Sheets("xxx")
Set names = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D1882")      ‘yyy workbook
Set schedName = Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("F4:F300")
Set schedDates = Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("J2:NZ2")

For Each n In names       ‘working in yyy workbook
If n.Value <> "" Then
    Set dates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(n.Offset(0, -3).Address)
    nameStr = n.Value
    dateStr = dates.Value
    If n.Value = schedName.Find(n.Value) Then
        Set x = Range(Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("F4:F300").Find(nameStr).Address)
        Set y = Range(Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("J2:NZ2").Find(dates.Value).Address)
        If n.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Sick Leave" Then
            If Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "Sick" Or Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "Sick - pending" Or Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "Half-day Sick" Then
            With n
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End With
            Else:
            With n
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            GoTo a:
            End If
        ElseIf n.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Holiday Annual Leave" Then
            If Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "Hol. Approved" Or Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "Half-day Hol." Then
            With n
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End With
            Else:
            With n
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            GoTo a:
            End If
        ElseIf n.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Leave  - Unpaid" Then
            If Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "TimeOff Approv." Or Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx").Cells(x.Row, y.Column).Value = "Unavailable" Then
            With n
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End With
            Else:
            With n
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            GoTo a:
            End If
        End If
        MsgBox x.Address & " " & y.Address
        Else: GoTo a:
    End If
    Else: GoTo a:
End If
a: Next
```

Comment: `Workbooks("xxx.xlsm")` is not correct.... a workbook name is not the same as a filename.

Comment: if I remove a .xlsm format, I get the "subject is out of range" error. I have both files open as well...

Comment: Not sure why you are using `Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets...` when you have already qualified object: `WBschedule`. I would just use `WBschedule.Sheets...`. Also, is **Workbooks("xxx.xlsm")** already open?

Comment: There's a fair amount wrong with the code:  you need to declare the data type of each variable - `y` is a range, but the other variables on that line are variants.  Same with `wb` and `ws`.  `Set ws=Sheets("Sheet1")` - is that meant to refer to the currently activeworkbook as you've not said which book it's in.  `Set dates` - you're setting it to the address value of n  - 3 columns, why not just set it to reference n-3 columns as both refs are on the same sheet:  `Set dates = n.Offset(, -3)`.  `Set x = Range...` - does sheet `xxx ` really have a space after it?

Comment: yeah, I started off using the wbschedule, but then had issues with that, and just switched to using the entire thing, as it's a very specific set of files and I first wanted to get the basic function working, and optimise later. and yeah, both files are open always

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, righto, the sheet1 bit is from file yyy, I only define that one, as file xxx only has the sheet called "xxx". Btw, doesn't have a space, that's me being trash at replacing all names with xxx. Just to clarify the file name's XXX.xlsm and the sheet name in the file is XXX, so it's the same. The yyy.xlsm workbook has a "sheet1" only.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, and regarding the "dates" and "set x =" they're define in different files, i.e. yyy and xxx respectively. I guess it was just easier for me to define the dates bit, than to refer to it the same  all the time, I'll try to remove any extra variables and see if it'll help

Answer (score 1):

For your specific problem (there are others in your code):

```
Set y = Range(Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("J2:NZ2").Find(dates.Value).Address)
```

If `dates.value` doesn't exist in your sheet you'll get an `Object variable or With block variable not set` error.

This is because you're telling it to find the value and return it's address.  You should try and find the value, check if it's found and then look at the address.

You also don't need to wrap it in a `Range` as the `FIND` function returns a range reference anyway.

```
Set y = Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("J2:NZ2").Find(dates.Value)
If Not y Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox y.Address
    'Other code that relies on y.
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Darren. I actually updated the text somewhat to go around the particular issue, although it's technically still there. Lemme explain this a bit - it seems that the find function cannot locate the date value in the date range. I've triple checked that the date appears correctly in the date range. I've also tried defining the date as long and looking for that, but neither works for some odd reason.The date range is basically 01/01/2017 to 29/12/2017. When I debug the issue I can highlight the variables and see that the long or value is found correctly, but still no luck

Comment: ps. thanks a lot for sticking with my horrible explanation, I'm well aware of convoluted nature of my explanations, so apologies for that :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I just decided to change the range.find function to the "for each..." way and found the necessary cell this way. Still no idea why .find didn't work, but the issues is basically not present anymore. For reference: I changed the following

```
 Set y = Range(Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx ").Range("J2:NZ2").Find(dates.Value).Address)
```

to the following:

```
    For Each d In Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("xxx").Range("J2:NZ2")
    If d = dates.Value Then
    Set y = d
    Else: GoTo b
    End If
b:         Next
```

Thanks everyone for good tips!